# How would I iterate over a list of files and plot them as subplots on a single figure?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot files onto 8 subplots for 2 figures. I am using a for loop and enumerate operator, along with axarray to do this.
I am almost there with the last step (with axarray) but need guidance as to how to finish it. 
Here's my code:

```
'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import parse_gctoo
import glob
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()

def histo_plotter(file, plot_title, ax):
    # read in file as string
    GCT_object = parse_gctoo.parse(file)
    # for c in range(9):
    #     print type(GCT_object.data_df.iloc[0][c])
    # computing median of rows in data_df
    # gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df.quantile(q=0.5,axis=1)
    # plot_title = "Gene expression levels for {}".format(cell)
    if plot_title == "ZSPCQNORM":
        gene_means = GCT_object.data_df.mean(axis=1)
        #making histogram of means
        ax.hist(gene_means)
        plt.title("MeanGeneExpressionZSPCQNORM")
        plt.xlabel("MedianGeneExpression")
        plt.ylabel("Count")
    elif plot_title == "QNORM":
        gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df.median(axis=1)
        #making histogram of medians
        ax.hist(gene_medians)
        plt.title("MedianGeneExpressionQNORM")
        plt.xlabel("MedianGeneExpression")
        plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.show()
f.savefig("hist_example1.png")



# plt.ylim(-1, 1)
# plt.xlim(-1,1)

# histo_plotter("/Users/eibelman/Desktop/ZSCOREDATA-    CXA061_SKL_48H_X1_B29_ZSPCQNORM_n372x978.gct.txt", "ZSPCQNORM", ax1)
#     histo_plotter("/Users/eibelman/Desktop/NewLJP005_A375_24H_X2_B19_QNORM_n373x978.gct.txt", "QNORM", ax1)
#########



# Create list of x2 LJP005 cell line files

z_list = glob.glob("/Volumes/cmap_obelix/pod/custom/LJP/roast/LJP005_[A375, A549, BT20, HA1E, HC515, HEPG2, HS578T, HT29]*X2*/zs/*ZSPCQNORM*.gct")
q_list = glob.glob("/Volumes/cmap_obelix/pod/custom/LJP/roast/LJP005_[A375, A549, BT20, HA1E, HC515, HEPG2, HS578T, HT29]*_X2_*/*_QNORM_*.gct")



# for loop which allows plotting multiple files in a single figure

f, axarray = plt.subplots(2, 4)
for n, single_q in enumerate(q_list):
     # axarray = plt.subplot(len(q_list), 1, n+1)
     axarray = histo_plotter(n, "QNORM", ax1)
    # axarray[n].plot()
plt.show()

# f, axarray = plt.subplots(2, 4)
# for n, single_z in enumerate(z_list):
#     # ax = plt.subplot(len(z_list), 1, n+1)
#     histo_plotter(single_z, "ZSPCQNORM", ax1)'
```

Comment: what type of plot? Can you show histo_plotter? do you want multiple subplots on 1 figure or multiple lines (histograms?) on one plot?

Comment: @story645 I added to histo_plotter. I want multiple subplots on 1 figure. Sorry for the formatting -- I'm not sure how to properly configure it.

Comment: @story645 are you able to figure it out?

Comment: I'm still not sure we're referring to the same things. Please read this http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part1-Figures_Subplots_and_layouts.ipynb
and then confirm

Comment: @story645 Thank you. What do you think of using the approach I just added to the question?

Comment: every time you call plt.figure(), you're creating a new figure. @heltonbiker's approach is the one I'd suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

for n, single_q in enumerate(q_list):
    ax = plt.subplot(len(q_list), 1, n+1)
    GCT_object = parse_gctoo.parse(single_q)
    gene_medians = GCT_object.data_df.median(axis=1)
    plt.hist(gene_medians)
    # tweak title, labels, etc.

plt.show()
```

Explaining:

- `enumerate` iterates over the items (`s`) while also returning their indices (`n`);
- the function `subplot(size, column, row)` requires these parameters: `size` is the total amount of subplots in the figure, and `row` and `column` determine the position for the current plot. `n+1` is necessary to put the plot in the correct position along the plot grid;
- I edited the rest of the code with your own data

Comment: Could you please explain what each step does? That would be very helpful!

Comment: Thank you! Why did you save the fourth line in ax?

Comment: it doesn't seem like this code is working... I used the for loop you suggested for the q_list and copied another one for z_list. I'm getting gibberish figures.

Comment: HI @heltonbiker. I have improved my code with your suggestions. Perhaps you could help me finish it?

Comment: @user8669 Nice! How can I help you?

Answer (score 1):

First, it's suffice to call `plt.figure()` once at the beginning of the loop.

Second, you need to use `subplot` correctly. Here is the doc of the `subplot` function:

> Typical call signature:
>
> subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number) Where nrows and ncols are used to
>   notionally split the figure into nrows * ncols sub-axes, and
>   plot_number is used to identify the particular subplot that this
>   function is to create within the notional grid. plot_number starts at
>   1, increments across rows first and has a maximum of nrows * ncols.
>
> **EDIT**

If you want a new figure for each file, then on each iteration you should call `plt.figure()` without arguments.

Comment: Thanks, @IsraelUnterman but I would like to create a for loop which would iterate through my list of files and plot each one as a subplot on a single figure. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: @user8669 I edited my answer for a new figure for each file.