# Plotting Multiple Plots on a single figure from within a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have reviewed the response to this question: [How would I iterate over a list of files and plot them as subplots on a single figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727364/how-would-i-iterate-over-a-list-of-files-and-plot-them-as-subplots-on-a-single-f)

But am none the wiser on how to achieve my goal. I would like to plot multiple data sets, with differing x axes, onto a single figure in Python. I have included a snippet of my code below, which performs an FFT on a dataset, then calculates 3 Butterworth filter outputs. Ideally I would like to have all  plotted on a single figure, which I have attempted to achieve in the code below.
The for loop calculates the 3 Butterworth filter outputs, the code above - the FFT and the code directly below attempts to append the FFT curve and sqrt(0.5) line to the previously generated plots for display.

Any Direction or advice would be appreciated.

```
"""Performs a Fast Fourier Transform on the data specified at the base of the code"""
def FFT(col):
    x = io2.loc[1:,'Time']
    y = io2.loc[1:,col]
    # Number of samplepoints
    #N = 600
    N = pd.Series.count(x)
    N2 = int(N/2)
    # sample spacing
    #T = 1.0 / 800.0
    T = 1/(io2.loc[2,'Time'] - io2.loc[1,'Time'])
    #x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
    #y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
    yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N2)

fig=plt.figure()
plt.clf()
i=1
for order in [3, 6, 9]:
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111, label="order = %d" % order)
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=2000)

    ax.plot((fs * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, abs(h))
    i=i+1

ax4=fig.add_subplot(111, label='sqrt(0.5)', frame_on=False)
ax5=fig.add_subplot(111, label="FFT of "+col, frame_on=False)

ax4.plot([0, 0.5 * fs], [np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)], '--')
ax5.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N2]))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Gain')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc='best')

#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#ax.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N2]), label="FFT of "+col)
plt.axis([0,5000,0,0.1])
#plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
#plt.ylabel('Amplitude (mm)')
#plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()

return
```

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find a minimal example of how to plot multiple lines with different *x* and *y* datasets. You are recreating the plot every time you type `add_subplot(111)`. Instead, you should call `plot` multiple times. I have added an example for a single plot with multiple lines, as well as an example for one subplot per line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
x2 = np.arange(3, 12, 0.1)
x3 = np.arange(2, 8, 0.01)

y1 = np.sin(x1)
y2 = np.cos(x2**0.8)
y3 = np.sin(4.*x3)**3

data = []
data.append((x1, y1, 'label1'))
data.append((x2, y2, 'label2'))
data.append((x3, y3, 'label3'))

# All lines in one plot.
plt.figure()
for n in data:
    plt.plot(n[0], n[1], label=n[2])
plt.legend(loc=0, frameon=False)

# One subplot per data set.
cols = 2
rows = len(data)//2 + len(data)%2
plt.figure()
gs = plt.GridSpec(rows, cols)
for n in range(len(data)):
    i = n%2
    j = n//2
    plt.subplot(gs[j,i])
    plt.plot(data[n][0], data[n][1])
    plt.title(data[n][2])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, the code you posted works if I split the filter function into individual parts, I have not yet tried it within the loop structure originally posted. Is it possible to add labels to each of the lines and a legend using this method? Again I have tried unsuccessfully to get this to work.

Comment: I elaborated the example with legends. Maybe the unzip command (the asterix) confused you.

Comment: Great, Thank you again. 
It doesn't take much to confuse me, but to be honest I didn't notice the asterix. I will have to google this unzip command I think.